# I'm running cassandra in a docker container. Where are the files generated by copying a cassandra table stored?

Tags: docker, cassandra

I created a docker container running cassandra with this command:

`docker run --name cass -p 9042:9042 -p 7199:7199 -p 9160:9160 -d cassandra:3.0.14`.

Then I ran `docker run -it --link cass:cassandra --rm cassandra:2.2.5 sh -c 'exec cqlsh "$CASSANDRA_PORT_9042_TCP_ADDR" --cqlversion="3.3.1"'` to enter my container and copy a table to a file.
But I can't find the table on the docker instance. Where would the file be written?

Answer (score 1):

Data is inside the Docker, and they are removed when container is destroyed.

Until you run the Docker something like this, data will stay inside:

```
docker run --rm -v /my/own/datadir:/some/dir cassandra
```

in this case, it will mount your own data directory on host `/my/own/datadir` into `/some/dir` inside container & you'll need to copy table into this location.